# Login button not rendered when not logged in

Tags: authentication, facebook-login

I have the following simple test page and trying to add a FB login button. This will be part of a stand along web site and not a canvas application. If the current user is already logged in on FB, then the list of friends using the application is displayed, but there is no login button. If the current user is not logged in on FB then I get nothing.
Any ideas?
Here is my page... I'm currently running it under localhost.

```
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root">
        </div>
        <!-- Loading of FB SDK -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                    appId: '319067848117743', // App ID
                    channelUrl: 'http://localhost/TestApp/channel.aspx', // Channel File
                    status: true, // check login status
                    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                    xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
                });
            };

            // Load the SDK Asynchronously
            (function (d) {
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
            } (document));
        </script>
        <!-- Display FB Login Button -->
        <script>        (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=319067848117743";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-max-rows="2" data-scope="user_about_me,publish_stream,read_stream">
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you don't really need to put in the async js loader twice, just redundant code is all.  Secondly,  I don't know how that code could list friends, I don't see the code for it.

1) You say you're expecting a log-in button even though the person is already logged in?   The login button plugin you're using doesn't work that way.  It will only show login if the user is not logged into your application. See the note saying "*Note: If the user is already logged in, no login button is shown.*" on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

2) You also say you cannot see any login button when the user is logged out of Facebook.  This is odd, but without seeing all the code I don't know what to help with that part of your question.

Comment: I'm not sure which code is duplicated exactly. I tried to follow the documentation. The part bellow the <!-- Display FB Login Button --> I found it in the page for the login plugin. And the code above that I find it in the page describing how to include the jscript SDK of FB, which is mentioned as prerequisite of the login plugin.
Regarding the friends list, I'm talking about the pictures of friends already using the application.
1) Perhaps I'm wrong, but no matter what I should be seeing a button when the current user is not logged in on FB, right?.
2) That is all the code that I have.

Comment: You will need more code than what you've posted to make it work.  I don't see any code there to list out the friends.  Can you share a link to your page where we can look at your code?

Comment: Thanks for willing to help. Perhaps my code is not enough, but this is what I have for now. Everything that you see in the initial post. Just copy that into an empty htm page and that's it.

Comment: How and where does this happen "If the current user is already logged in on FB, then the list of friends using the application is displayed"?

Answer (score 0):

Is your app on sandbox mode? Try disabling sandbox mode from app facebook config.